# Azure Pipeline Ruby Step fails without error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I build a rubygem on Azure DevOps. I used that step to use RSpec:

script: bundle exec rspec spec --format RspecJunitFormatter --out test_results/TEST-rspec.xml 
displayName: 'rake spec'

While execution i'm getting that issue: https://dev.azure.com/saigkill/hoe-manns/_build?definitionId=3

So it returns '1' without any error before. Maybe i have missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written [there](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/402418/ruby-pipeline-fails-without-error.html) a system.debug = true helped me, to identify the problem. One of my tests failed.